# How to get sdcard path in android using ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, file, ionic-framework

I'm new in ionic framework.I need to get sdcard path from device using ionic framework.I refer below links

http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/

As per reference.i have create below code

```
$cordovaFile.createFile(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, "new_file.txt", true).then(function (success) {
        alert('success');
    }, function (error) {
      // error
      alert('error');
    });
```

**console.log(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory)**

finally i'm getting below output

/Storage/emulated/0/ -----------interal storage (not sd card)

How to get sdcard path ????????